# Get IP address of created instance in Ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that uses

```
include: launch.yml
```

to create an AWS EC2 instance. I then have

```
hosts: server-launch
sudo: yes
gather_facts: yes
vars_files:
    - vars.yml

roles:
  - { role: "role1" }
  - { role: "role2" }
  - { role: "stop aws instance", ip_address: "" }
```

I'm not sure how to grab the IP address and send it explicitly to the stop aws instance role. How can I go about this? This is for Ansible v2.1.1.0.

Comment: I'm not at liberty to post the literal code, but I can clarify where necessary. What I posted is, with exception of the names, hardly different from the actual code.

Comment: How do you get the IP adress after you launch the instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up not using the ec2 implementations in Ansible to resolve this issue. Instead I added the following lines to the "role2" mentioned above:

```
- name: restart machine
  shell: sleep 2 && shutdown -r now "Ansible updates triggered"
  async: 1
  poll: 0
  sudo: true
  ignore_errors: true

- name: waiting for server to come back
  local_action: wait_for host={{ inventory_hostname }} state=started delay=30 timeout=300
  sudo: false
```

found [here](https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201958037-Reboot-a-server-and-wait-for-it-to-come-back). That has been working well.